# Video won't play on second call

Tags: android, video, dialog

With the following code in the `onCreateDialog` i open a `Dialog` which shows a video.

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.video_dialog);

final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test2));
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
videoView.start();
```

This works great the first time I call it. but if I cancel the `Dialog` by pressing the back button and open that `Dialog` again the video doesn't start. The Dialog opens up but I can only see the black background of the `Dialog`.

I tried setting an `OnCancelListener` so i can make sure video is stoped and the dialog is not used again by doing the following

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    videoView.stopPlayback();
    //videoView.suspend();
    dialog = null;
}
```

Neither `stopPlayback()` nor `suspend()` did the trick.

**Can anyone tell what may cause this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your code in [onPrepareDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog%29).The first time you run in the dialog is created so onCreateDialog is called but the second time the dialog is already created and only onPrepareDialog is called. Little more [info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog) about dialogs

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, seems kinda obvious ;) Thanks though!